# How to mock a quasar component

Tags: jestjs, vuejs3, vue-test-utils, quasar

This is my code for a quasar component that I want to mock

```
emits: [
"buyer-protection",
...useDialogPluginComponent.emits
]
```

But I get the following error:

```
TypeError: _quasar.useDialogPluginComponent.emits is not iterable
```

I'd like to mock `useQuasar` and `usePluginDialogComponent` from the quasar module. I tried to mock them this way:

```
jest.mock('quasar', () => ({
  useDialogPluginComponent: () =>  ({
    emits: []
  }),
  useQuasar: () => ({
    platform: {
      is: {
        desktop: true
      }
    }
  })
}))
```

How can I mock these quasar components?

Answer (score 1):

I tried to mock useDialogPluginComponent, too.
But I realized that installQuasarPlugin() will handle all Quasar plugins, so I don't need to mock any plugin by myself.

But It has to create the instance by mount, don't use `shallowMount`, that is make sure `dialogRef = vue.ref(null)` will catch q-dialog.

For my example, I want to check 'onDialogOK' has been called, but I can't track 'onDialogOK' by spyOn, so I check the `wrapper.vm` emitted.

```
expect(vueWrapper.emitted()).toHaveProperty('ok');
```

It works.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure why **useDialogPluginComponent** is both a function instance and object instance.
As a workaround, I have defined a function and assigned emits object to it.

```
jest.mock("quasar", () => {
  let t1 = () => {
    return {
      dialogRef: {},
      onDialogHide: () => {},
      onDialogOK: () => {},
      onDialogCancel: () => {}
    }      
  };
  t1.emits = ['ok', 'hide'];
  return {
    useQuasar: () => ({
      platform: {
        is: {
          Mobile: true,
        },
      },
    }),
    useDialogPluginComponent: t1
  }
});
```